PC automatically ejecting USB-C Hard Drive while copying
So I'm a video editor and I use a RAID system for storage, I recently upgraded my motherboard, CPU, and changed whole PC case out to a NZXT H9 Flow case.
I recently have run into an issue where my drives attached the to USB-C interface on the front or the back of the PC case just eject while under heavy load. I'll copy around 40-70GB and it'll just eject mid transfer and then reappear. It also seems to do it when I'm copying multiple files at once, if I copy one file at a time (even if it's 150GB) it will still copy.
I'm not quite sure what could be causing it, is it possible it's just the USB-C ports on the case? I've tried the disks on another computer and it doesn't seem to have a problem. Could it be a BIOS issue? My bios firmware is from 2022, not sure how to update it. I'm running a Asus Prime X299 motherboard.
Also worth mentioning, it'll be copying at like 240MB/s and have no dip in speed before it just ejects.

Are you on Windows? What's your motherboard?
